# Why did Apache IoTDB filled data in aligned time series but reported "timeseries not aligned" error?

Tags: apache-iotdb

What is the reason for judging whether the time series is aligned when the data is written to Apache IoTDB? My empty data is filled with `null`  as aligned data, and a `timeseries under this device are not aligned`  error is reported when I used `insertTablet` to write data. Does anyone know why this happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Apache IoTDB does not judge if the time series is aligned or not. You need to specify if you want the time series to be aligned when you create this time series. You can refer to the time series creation chapter in the user manual to see more.